# how to customize the template content in wromapping.properties of WRO4J?

Tags: java, web, wro4j, jscompress

I use wro4j  to minimize my front end resource files, such as *.js and *.css, to reduce page load time in my Spring application. wro4j will generate a file called  'wromapping.properties' to record the generated files' names.
the first two lines in it looks usually like this:

```
#Mapping of defined group name to renamed group name
#Fri Jun 24 10:06:26 CST 2016
```

what i need is **to delete the timestamp line** which is the second line, or change it to certain fixed context.

what should i do to manage to get my goal? Thanks!